# "Inverse" of the transitive closure of a weighted graph

Tags: r, algorithm, igraph

For a network, I am given the (non-negative) travel costs between each pair of nodes. The travel costs are additive. How can I prune the graph so that unnecessary edges are removed (i.e. those that have a path with approximately equivalent length)? In other words, I'm looking for a smaller (a smallest?) graph where the shortest-path distance between each pair of nodes is preserved.

In the following example, I'm given `sp` (or `spg`, for that matter), and I would like to infer `g` from it:

```
set.seed(144)
library(igraph)
nv <- 100
ne <- 300

g <- erdos.renyi.game(nv, ne, "gnm", directed = FALSE)
edge.attributes(g) <- list(weight = rexp(ne, 1))
sp <- shortest.paths(g)
spg <- graph.adjacency(sp, weighted = "weight")
```

I have a few thousand nodes, so enumerating all connected pairs of edges is not an option (due to memory limitations), and iterating over all pairs of nodes will be probably too slow when implemented in R.

Comment: How about just calculating shortest paths between all pairs of vertices, taking the union of edges from them, and throwing away all other edges?

Comment: Btw. this seems to be a full graph, so this is not quite optimal for igraph, which is optimized for sparse graphs.

Comment: I see, sorry, I had no time to actually read it, when commenting....